# On or Off topic: Is wordpress good for such a type of site

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering if a question like this would be on topic, or would be better suited elsewhere:

> I want to make a site that has this and does this. Is Wordpress a good
>   or okay choice for this?

Comment: It seems like it could be a very opinionated type of question and may divulge into "Well, how would you do feature 'A' in WordPress" conversation/debate. May be better suited for the [WordPress forums](https://wordpress.org/support/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WordPress can be used to build any kind of site, but is it good for your use case? I believe this is an opinion based question, and is thus offtopic

[image]

That's not to say it's a bad question, but it's a discussion topic rather than something with a concrete answer.

Rare exceptions would be nuclear safety protocols, Rocket engine controller software, micro-controller firmware, all of these would have a concrete answer of no

Comment: where is the +10 for the last paragraph :)

Answer (score 4):

That wouldn't be a good question for our site, because the answer can be just a *yes* or *no*, depending on the opinion of the answering person.

A better approach would be to ask: *How can I solve this task with WordPress?* That might still be too broad, but if you do your homework first and explain the specific problems that you couldn't solve with your own research, it might be on topic and get good answers.

Answer (score -1):

I would formulate like this — it *would* be a decent question **if** you can provide enough details for a definitive conclusion.

Note that in most cases it's simply *impossible* requirement to achieve. It might take quite a bit of research (more so for less experienced WP developers) to estimate is it a reasonable fit.

And dev, experienced with WP, would likely not need to ask such *general* questions, but would ask about *specific* implementation challenges.

In a nutshell — unlikely to be a good question, with rare exceptions.

Comment: I would downvote if I could because an "experienced dev" in general may need to ask such *general* questions if they know nothing about Wordpress development specifically. An "experienced *WP* dev" may be a different story however.

Comment: Yes, _WP_ dev is exactly what I meant so say, sorry. :) Just slipped out of the sentence.

Comment: Got ya, okay. I'm taking online WP training courses at teamtreehouse.com, so hopefully I can assess myself soon. Thank you.